# React Usereducer action payload

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, action, payload

In the below code, I could not understand action.payload. Please clear it in a simple way.

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import NotesContext from '../context'

function Note({ note }) {
    const {dispatch}  = useContext(NotesContext)
    return (
        <div className="note">
            <p>{note.text}</p>
            <div className="btn-container">
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'SET_CURRENT_NOTE', payload:note})} className="edit">Edit</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'DELETE_NOTE', payload:note.id})} className="delete">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
} 
export default Note



export default function reducer(state, action) {
 switch(action.type) {
         case 'SET_CURRENT_NOTE':
         return {
             ...state,
             currentNote: action.payload
         }
         case 'DELETE_NOTE':
           const deleteNotes = state.notes.filter(
               note => note.id !== action.payload
           )

           return {
               ...state,
               notes: deleteNotes
           }
         default:
         return state;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So when an action is dispatched it is caught in the reducer. This code here is dispatching the action

```
dispatch({type: 'SET_CURRENT_NOTE', payload:note})
```

This can be written like this:

```
const action = {type: "SET_CURRENT_NOTE", payload: note}

dispatch(action)
```

Now in the reducer you have access to that action object you passed into `dispatch`.
From that object you can access the properties `type` and `payload` via dot notation like this:

```
action.type
action.payload
```

Then you simply catch the matching `action.type` in the switch case, then update the state with the returned object from the reducer.

Comment: You have explained it very simply. Anyone can understand your answer. Once again many thanks.

Comment: Is action a protected keyword and/or special object in JS? Seems unclear from google/so searches. From your answer, it doesn't appear so and action is just some idiomatic, useReducer syntax maybe?